# How to call SignalR Hub Method that has Enum parameters with a Javascript Client?

Tags: signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

Using a C# signalR client is straight forward, and it works; but I am stuck with a JS client.

```
 public async Task MyHubMethod(string userName, CityEnum city, FruitEnum fruit) {
    //etc.
 }
 
public enum CityEnum
{
    LONDON,
    LISBON,
    RIO,
    SYDNEY
}

public enum FruitEnum
{
    APPLES,
    BANANAS,
    ORANGES
}

//C# Client, YAY it works !
    string userName = "mindi-mink";
    CityEnum city = CityEnum.LONDON;
    FruitEnum fruit = FruitEnum.APPLES;
    await _connection.InvokeAsync("MyHubMethod", userName, city, fruit);
    

//Javascript Client:
    ???
```

Not sure what to do, other than changing the server method to take string parameters, and convert them back to Enums server-side;

How to do it from the Javascript signalR client? (without changing the server method signature).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enum values are integers, surely passing integers should work?

Yes, just tested and it does work!

Define objects to match your Server-side enums

```
const CityEnum = {
    LONDON : 101,
    LISBON : 102,
    RIO : 103,
    SYDNEY : 104,
}

const FruitEnum = {
    APPLES     : 0,
    BANANAS    : 1,
    ORANGES    : 2,
}

//JS-Client:
const userName = "mind-mink";
const city = CityEnum.LONDON;
const fruit = FruitEnum.APPLES;

await _hubCnn.invoke("MyHubMethod", userName, city, fruit);
```